# Moving/copying Representation Marker to Marker Symbol using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, style, representation

I have a *custom.style* file with the *marker1* Representation Marker.

Is there any way to move/copy *marker1* to Marker Symbols?

(I'm using ArcGIS 10.5.1)

[image]

Comment: I think the short answer is no. Representations have sets of rules to define them, something markers do not have so I don't think you can just copy them into a completely different class of symbology? Happy for someone to prove me wrong!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but in my understanding, representations belong to feature classes. Here I don't have a feature class, just a .style file. The representation marker in this file seems a simple symbol to me. I can create the same symbol in Marker Symbols. However it would be much easier if I could just copy it. (Especially when I have more representation markers.)